# php foreach((array) $a->b as $a) returning "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" error

Tags: php, xml, jsp

To check to see if each `foreach()` statement applies to an array, the first argument in each statement is `(array)`. Despite this argument, the below code isn't returning any data.

The script is designed to pull applicable data from the FAA's XML Airport Status JSP file (http://www.fly.faa.gov/flyfaa/xmlAirportStatus.jsp) given the data supplied via the `$airports` variable.

Upon removal of the `(array)` argument in each `foreach()` statement, the script returns applicable data but also returns the following warning:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.fly.faa.gov/flyfaa/xmlAirportStatus.jsp");
$airports = array('ATL','AUS','BOS','DEN','LAS','LGA','LGB','JFK','OAK','PDX','PHX','RNO','SAN','SAT','SEA','SFO','SJC','SLC','SMF');
$effected = array();
$count = 0;
foreach((array) $xml->Delay_type as $Delay) {
    foreach((array) $Delay->Ground_Stop_List->Program as $Program) {
        if(in_array($Program->ARPT, $airports)) {
            $effected[] = $Program->ARPT;
            if($count == 0) {
                echo '<div class="alert">';
            }
            echo 'Departure traffic destined to <b>'.$Program->ARPT.'</b> is being held at its origin due to <b>'.$Program->Reason.'</b> until <b>'.$Program->End_Time.'</b><br />';
            $count++;
        }
    }
    foreach((array) $Delay->Ground_Delay_List->Ground_Delay as $Ground_Delay) {
        if(in_array($Ground_Delay->ARPT, $airports)) {
            $effected[] = $Ground_Delay->ARPT;
            if($count == 0) {
                echo '<div class="alert">';
            }
            /* effected[] = $Ground_Delay->ARPT; */
            echo 'Departure traffic destined to <b>'.$Ground_Delay->ARPT.'</b> is facing an average delay of <b>'.$Ground_Delay->Avg.'</b> due to <b>'.$Ground_Delay->Reason.'</b><br />';
            $count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no need to typecast into the array, its spewed some error because there's no ground stop list data in your xml

Comment: Thanks, @Ghost. I see the problem now. Would it be safe to insert `if` statements before each `foreach()` statement to verify that an array exists?

Comment: yeah you could include a condition before iteration, `!empty` or similar should suffice

Comment: SOLVED: Added `if(empty($Delay->))` before each `foreach()` statement.